# Not understanding this error on Linq to Sql

Tags: linq, class, vba, object, visual-studio-2008

Ok i have a class, a dbml file and a form. My project is called "Demo Project"

Form - DriveTimeActiveVendorsFrom
dbml - Dataworld
class - tblDriveTimeActiveVendors

My form contains the following code

```
 Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping

 Public Class DriveTimeActiveVendorsForm

Private dc As New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
Dim _insert As New tblDrivetimeActiveVendors

Private Sub insertVendor()
    dc = New DataworldDataContext.DataworldDataContext
    _insert.ASRVendor = TextBox1.Text
    _insert.AddressLine1 = TextBox2.Text
    _insert.City = TextBox3.Text
    dc.tblDriveTimeActiveVendors.InsertOnSubmit(_insert)
End Sub

 End Class
```

My class contains the following

```
 Public Class tblDrivetimeActiveVendors


Private _ASRVendor As String = Nothing
Private _AddressLine1 As String = Nothing
Private _City As String = Nothing



Public Property ASRVendor() As String
    Get
        Return _ASRVendor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If value Is Nothing Then
            _ASRVendor = Nothing
        Else
            _ASRVendor = value.Trim
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property AddressLine1() As String
    Get
        Return _AddressLine1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If value Is Nothing Then
            _AddressLine1 = Nothing
        Else
            _AddressLine1 = value.Trim
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property City() As String
    Get
        Return _City
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If value Is Nothing Then
            _City = Nothing
        Else
            _City = value.Trim
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Im getting an error on the following line

```
    dc.tblDriveTimeActiveVendors.InsertOnSubmit(_insert)
```

Its the "_insert" part and the error is

```
    Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.tblDrivetimeActiveVendors' cannot be converted to 'WindowsApplication1.DataworldEntity.tblDriveTimeActiveVendor'.    C:\Users\rmonzing\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DemoProject\DemoProject\DriveTimeActiveVendorsForm.vb   13  53  DemoProject
```

What am i missing here? Thanks

Comment: Are you using an ORM framework (like Entity Framework) to map your database objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `_insert` is declared as an object of type `tblDrivetimeActiveVendors` (plural), but `InsertOnSubmit` is expecting an object of type `tblDrivetimeActiveVendor' (singular).

Somewhere in your code, something has already declared a class `tblDrivetimeActiveVendor`, which (presumably) contains properties that correspond to the columns in your database table.  You need to use this object instead of the class that you posted above.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've stared at a "cannot be converted" error for an hour before realizing I was ignoring the 's' on the end of one of the types!